# decide the route based on the initialization phase of flutter_native_splash

Tags: flutter, splash-screen

I'm writing a flutter application using flutter 2.10 and I'm debugging it using an Android Emulator

I included the flutter_native_splash plugin from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash and I use version 2.0.1+1

the problem that I'm having is that I decide what's the first screen that the user will see based on the initialization phase. I check the stored user token, see his premissions, verify them with the server, and forward him to him relevant route.

since the `runApp()` function executes in the background while the initialization phase is running I cannot choose the page that will be shown. and if I try to nativgate to a route in the initialization function I get an exception.

as a workaround for now I created an `init_home` route with FutureBuilder that awaits for a global variable called `GeneralService.defaultRoute` to be set and then changes the route.

```
class _InitHomeState extends State<InitHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: () async {
          var waitCount=0;
          while (GeneralService.defaultRoute  == "") {
            waitCount++;
            await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
            if (waitCount>20) {
              break;
            }
          }
          if (GeneralService.defaultRoute == "") {
            return Future.error("initialization failed");
          }
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(GeneralService.defaultRoute);
          ...
```

any ideas how to resolve this issue properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I use a Stateful widget as Splash Screen.
In the build method, you just return the 'loading' view such as Container with a background color etc. (with texts or whatever you like but just consider it as the loading screen).

In the initState(), you call a function that we can name redirect(). This should be an async function that performs the queries/checks and at the end, calls the Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed etc.

```
class _SplashState extends State<Splash> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    redirect();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(color: Colors.blue);
  }

  Future<void> redirect() async {
    var name = 'LOGIN';
    ... // make db calls, checks etc
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(name);
  }
}
```

Your `build` function just creates the loading UI, and the `redirect` function in the `initState` is the one running in the background and when it has finished computing, calls the Navigator.push to your desired page.